# Create AWS CodeBuild "An unspecified error occurred"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Trying to create an AWS CodeBuild resource, click "Create build project" and see this screen
I am able to create other AWS resources, but not this one.

[image: Error screen]

Comment: This seems like a transient issue with the Console. Can you check by creating a project in any other region to see if they exhibit same error.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion, I think you are right, the error is related to regions. Solved!

Comment: Hello @joevanbo , i am actually facing the same error, changed the region but still. Could you please tell me in which region it was solved for you ?